# ensuring search lowercase characters

Tags: mysql

How do I search lower case in MySQL?

I have the following

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE column LIKE '%$search%'";
```

How do I make sure the values in "column" are matched to lowercase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either set your column's collation to a case-sensitive one, like `UTF8_BIN`, or make an additional check in the filter:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_name
WHERE   column LIKE '%$search$%'
        AND column COLLATE UTF8_BIN = LOWER(column COLLATE UTF8_BIN)
```

Note that if your collation is case-insensitive, like `UTF8_GENERAL_CI`, then the following query:

```
SELECT  LOWER('A') = ('A')
```

will return true. You should explicitly coerce your column to a case-insensitive collation before doing a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm interpreting correctly, use the MySQL `LOWER()` function:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE LOWER(column) LIKE '%$search%'";
```

This will convert everything in `column` to lowercase before testing it against the search value.

Comment: This won't help if a case-insensitive collation is used (and the fact of the question implies it is).